# Average grades and "if"

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, average

My previous question got closed so I made a new one with the code provided.

```
assignments = 5

x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in     range(assignments)]


finalGrade = int(input('Ocena z kolokwium: '))

average_assignment_grade = (sum(x) + finalGrade) / 6

print()
print('Średnia')


for number in range(1):
    print(format(average_assignment_grade, '.1f'))

A.append(average_assignment_grade);



grades_sum = sum(A)
grades_average = grades_sum / 6
if grades_sum < 3 print ("Przedmiot nie zaliczony")
else print("Przedmiot zaliczony")
```

The error that I get:

```
File "<ipython-input-43-fe40b7e5825c>", line 23
if grades_sum < 3 print ("Przedmiot nie zaliczony")
```

So this is the code. As you can see I wanted it to show if the student has passed or not (it's in polish, "Przedmiot nie zaliczony" - not passed, "Przedmiot zaliczony" - passed) but I got invalid syntax error. I looked up my notes and I did everything like they say but obviously something is wrong and I have no idea what. Can you help now?

Comment: You have to show the error. it would be easier to debug the issue

Comment: You seem to be unfamiliar with python syntax. Please go through some basic tutorials such as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp). Which will tell you that you're missing `:` from the end of the `if` statements.

Comment: you are missing `:` in conditional statements, it should `if x:` or `else:`

Answer (score 0):

The error is about your if/else statement. You should write it like this:

```
if grades_sum < 3:
    print("something")
else:
    print("something else")
```

edit:

Also A is never defined in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

@joostblack Thank you, you helped me a lot. I know I lack of basic knowledge.
I wanted to take a step further and create a list of what "x" can be (2, 3, 4 or 5 only).
list(2, 3, 4, 5)

```
assignments = 5
A = 5

list = [2, 3, 4, 5]
x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(assignments)]

if x in list:
print("ok")
else:
print("no ok")
```

It shows this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Wojtek\Desktop\untitled2.py", line 9, in <module>
list(2, 3, 4, 5)

TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 4
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this list and why it says it can only contain 1 argument. The question is how to make the list able to have more than 1 argument and if written argument is not in the list it will show "no ok".

Comment: This should really be a question instead of an answer. First your print statements need to be indended. Secondly it is better to not name your list list,as the word list is already used for different things in python. Finally what do you want your code to do? Do you want to compare 5 user inputs and print 5 times ok/not ok ?